# Setting the form location is inconsistent

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to set the position of the only form in a WinForm C# project. However having set the position and verified it the form seems be positioned at a random point on the screen where X=Y.

Here is the code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Point MyPoint;
        public Form1()
        {
            MyPoint = new Point(300, 50);
            InitializeComponent();
            Location = MyPoint; 
        }  //Breakpoint 1

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Location = MyPoint; //Breakpoint 2
        }
    }
}
```

At breakpoint 1 Location and MyPoint are both 300,50, but the position of the form is not. Pressing the button and arriving at breakpoint 2 shows that Location = Z,Z where Z seems random but MyPoint = 300,50. Executing the button press moves the form to the expected position and all is then well.
I have tried this on VS 2015 and the latest VS2017. Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the startup position set to for your form?

Comment: Set the form's start up position to manual.

Comment: The start up position is 0,0. The actual position varies (208,208), (26,26) etc. The start position was set to "WindowsDefaultLocation". I changed this to "Manual" and this fixed the problem. So it seems that the "WindowsDefaultLocation" is random and applied after the form class is created. Thanks preciousbetine.